# How to use split a string and get all the values in array in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I am searching for a code that helps me let the same thing done as c# or c++ code.
Which is

```
string[] array = new string[5];
array = newstring.split(',');
```

The new `array` get stored all values one by one and i can loop through them sequentially.

Any one knows the answer please help me out?

Comment: The question is not clear, what are you trying to do, what have you tried?

Comment: And why on earth did you tag it with sql? Do you have comma separated values in columns? Read about normalization in databases.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support arrays as such for what you are trying to do, so you will have to use some [string manipulation functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) instead to achieve what you are after.

I would suggest a using things like: [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx), [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to find parts of the string based on the delimiter.

This [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/473174/CreateplusArrayplusinplusSqlplusServer) may also be useful.

Comment: i appreciate your answer but one thing i would like to know that **CHARINDEX** only get the index of character which it found or it get return the all the character occurrences.

Comment: CHARINDEX will find the first instance f the delimiter. You would have to go through the string recursively using those function to find an instance of the character and then cut that part of the string out until the whole string has been split up.